# Akka: is a DeathPactException always a programming error?

Tags: java, .net, akka, akka.net, akka-supervision

I sporadically use Akka.NET in my projects, so I know the technology, can do stuff with it, but do not consider myself an expert.

Although I use .NET, the question can certainly be answered by someone familiar with Akka on the JVM.

Recently, I came across a `DeathPactException` while looking at an application's log file. The cause was an actor (actor A1) that watched another actor (A2), which it had started itself. A1, however, did not handle the `Terminated` message sent by A2. Which was caused by A2 actually stopping itself after performing its task. Thanks to a reasonably-defined supervisor hierarchy etc. the system itself worked just fine: A1 was simply restarted by its supervisor immediately.

Is there actually any scenario where an actor would `.Watch()` another actor and then ignore the `Terminated` message? Or is the infamous `DeathPactException` basically always a bug in application code, similar to a `NullReferenceException`/`NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DeathPactException` does not necessarily indicate a programming error.

Deliberately not handling a `Terminated` message is a way to stop all of an actor's children when any one of that actor's children stops normally. The sequence of events is the following:

1. Actor `parent` watches all of its children, `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, but does not handle the `Terminated` message.
2. Child `c2` stops normally.
3. `parent` throws a `DeathPactException`, which causes `parent` to restart (this is the default supervisor strategy, which can be overridden in `parent`'s supervisor/parent).
4. `parent`'s `preRestart` hook is called, which by default stops all of `parent`'s children.

Choosing not to handle a `Terminated` message is effectively a means to enact an all-for-one stopping strategy for non-exceptional (i.e., not in response to a failure) cases.